# Rancher does not start. Waiting for Kubernetes API

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, rancher

Good day.

I'm new in kubernetes.

I have a kubernetes cluster with 3 hosts on Ubuntu 16.04.
Recently I noticed that this hosts doesn't have space in **/boot** partition.

[image: click]

I used **apt-get autoremove** to free some space in /boot on first host. And then **apt-get upgrade**.

I use Rancher (as docker container) to visualize my cluster.
So now when I start Rancher it's always **Waiting for Kubernetes API**.

[image: click]

Tried to restart Rancher container and no luck. Still **Waiting for Kubernetes API**.

I always found that there is no **kube-system** containers on first host.

[image: click]

Is there a way to get Rancher back to life?

Comment: Did you try restarting the whole system?

Comment: I tried to restart docker service on first host and it did not help. Then I restarted the first host, result was the same(

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a chance to make some free space in `/boot`? It's also possible etcd is not healthy since it needs a quorum of odd number of nodes. You could try deactivating two of the hosts, get the kubernetes stack to become healthy and then add the hosts back with enough disk space. It might also be a good idea to create a github issue with logs from etcd and other core k8s components.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just update the cluster by rancher and update the number of nodes to two then the cluster is updated and running